# Why this Goldbach's conjecture program does not work in Prolog?

Tags: math, error-handling, compiler-errors, prolog, instantiation-error

Why does this program does not work in Prolog ?

```
%  Goldbach's conjecture. 
% Goldbach's conjecture says that every positive even number greater 
% than 2 is the sum of two prime numbers. Example: 28 = 5 + 23.

:- ensure_loaded(p31).

% goldbach(N,L) :- L is the list of the two prime numbers that
%    sum up to the given N (which must be even).
%    (integer,integer) (+,-)

goldbach(4,[2,2]) :- !.
goldbach(N,L) :- N mod 2 =:= 0, N > 4, goldbach(N,L,3).

goldbach(N,[P,Q],P) :- Q is N - P, is_prime(Q), !.
goldbach(N,L,P) :- P < N, next_prime(P,P1), goldbach(N,L,P1).

next_prime(P,P1) :- P1 is P + 2, is_prime(P1), !.
next_prime(P,P1) :- P2 is P + 2, next_prime(P2,P1).
```

First off, I had to remove the code line :- ensure_loaded(p31). Otherwise marked an error saying that does not exist.

Second, when I run it on SWI-Prolog screen with ?-goldbach(4,X,Y). marked an error that says:

ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Why?

Could someone please help me to fix the program?

Thank you.

Comment: You only need exactly two addends, so I would not bother with a list. It just makes the predicate a little more cumbersome. And what's `p31`? Note that `is/2` is only for arithmetic evaluation when all of the variables of the 2nd argument are known numeric values. Try using CLP(FD).

Comment: ? ? ?............

Comment: Let me try another question, maybe this one is easier, although I assume you copied this code from somewhere else so you don't know how it works: why are you trying to call `goldbach(4, X, Y)`? The code comment clearly indicates that the top level is `goldbach/2`. You should be calling `goldbach(4, L)`.

Comment: @lurker oops seems like someone need glasses.. thank you for notice it.

Comment: you see, I'm not good at this I don't know how to code in Prolog although I know how to code in java and c. Just don't know why can't I learn prolog. Hence I try to find solved exercise on google.

Comment: What do I need to modify if I want to call in this style `goldbach(4,X,Y)` ?

Comment: You probably think `goldbach(4, X, Y)` will give you the two primes in `X` and `Y`, but this is not so. `goldbach(4, X)` will give you the two primes in a list in `X`. Prolog is quite different from other languages and you need to start reading an introduction to logic programming and actively solving simpler exercises. What you are looking at is a solved exercise in the middle of a complex sequence of exercises with dependencies between them.

Comment: It seems that you might want to start with simpler program examples and a tutorial or text book to learn the basics first.

Comment: Your question was about why the program doesn't work and could it be fixed. The answer has been given: you need to call the correct top level predicate: `goldbach(4, L)`. If you have a different specific question about a specific issue with programming in Prolog, you should post it separately. If you just want a 3-argument version of this program, you could write, `my_goldbach(N, X, Y) :- goldbach(N, [X,Y]).` and call `my_goldbach(4, X, Y).`

Comment: @lurker Would you mind to recommend notes or a book (easy to understand) for a beginner? I know I can google it, but I'd get a loot of material and I don't know what would the _best_ for me. And I ask you because I can see from your profile that you are an expert in Prolog. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A popular online tutorial for beginners is [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org). Another useful beginner site is [99 Prolog Problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/). This site poses simple Prolog problems you can try to solve and it gives the solution so you can compare. Always try yourself first before looking at the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that `goldbach/2` is the predicate being defined, which uses an auxiliary predicate `goldbach/3`. `goldbach/3` is called by `goldbach/2` when certain conditions on `N` are met in order to compute the doubleton `L`, using 3 as the initial value for the auxiliary parameter `P` of `goldbach/3`.

In fact, you can see that `goldbach/3` will always be called with its first and third parameters instantiated. The requirement on the first parameter is clear from the documentation of `goldbach/2`, which marks it as +; the third parameter is provided when `goldbach/2` calls its helper `goldbach/3` to perform the computation.

A call like `goldbach(4, X, Y)` fails because it tries to perform arithmetic (`Q is N - P`) involving uninstantiated variables, which results in an error: arithmetic on logic variables does not make sense to Prolog. To clarify, the program should work fine, but you are not supposed to call `goldbach/3` directly.

As it stands, the predicate `is_prime/1` is missing. The `ensure_loaded/1` directive you removed was looking for the file where this predicate would be defined (in this development).

Comment: In which part of the code should I write `is_prime/1` ? .It should be `ensure_loaded/1` instead of `ensure_loaded(p31)` ?

Comment: 1. It doesn't matter where you write it. 2. `ensure_loaded/1` is informal notation for the `ensure_loaded` predicate that takes 1 argument (note you can have several different predicates with the same name and different arity, this is at the core of the confusion).

Comment: I added  3 code lines `ensure_loaded/1.`,`is_prime/1.` and `my_goldbach(N, X, Y) :- goldbach(N, [X,Y]).`  and works correctly when I call `my_goldbach(4, X, Y).` but fails with `my_goldbach(8, X, Y).` Why is that?

Comment: There is still a source of confusion between the two `goldbach` predicates, but it is beyond the scope of the question as posed, and of what can reasonably be addressed in comments. Like @lurker, I think the most efficient way to proceed would be to work from simpler examples, isolate your problems on those, and ask concrete questions about them.